# Can one always modify normal crossing divisors to strict normal crossing by finite cover?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth algebraic variety, let $B$ be a normal crossing divisor on $X$. Can we always find a finite (ramified) cover $f\colon Y\to X$, such that $Y$ is smooth, and $f^{-1}B$ is a strictly normal crossing divisor?

Here is a simple case which I feel confused: Taking $X=\mathbb{A}^2$ and $B=V(y^2-x^3-x^2)$, does there exist a double cover $f:Y\to X$, such that $f^{-1}B$ is a union of two smooth rational curves meeting at two nodes (as depicted in Hartshorne Exercise III.10.6)? If there doesn't, intuitively what shall be the obstruction?

Comment: One simple obstruction is that $\mathbb{P}^2$ is simply connected. The double covering described by Hartshorne is étale, therefore it cannot come from a double covering of $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Comment: @abx Yes, let's replace $\mathbb{P}^2$ by $\mathbb{A}^2$, so that we can still take ramified covers along divisor disjoint from $B$, in this case, would there be a reason that Hartshorne's cover still does not come from covering of the ambient space? (If we are in char $p$, there are many more etale coverings of $\mathbb{A}^2$..)

Comment: For your example, you can take the ramified cover with coordinates $(\sqrt{x+1}, y)$.

Comment: @BotongWang Thanks! If we take $z=\sqrt{x+1}$, then $y^2=x^3+x^2$ pullback to $y^2=z^2(z-1)^2(z+1)^2$, there are two components with three nodal intersections, although it is not etale on $B$, it turns normal crossing to strict normal crossing!